# Without linked server how to data migration one server to another server using ssis?

Tags: ssis

I don't know how to migrate data one server to another server with different schema  names using dynamic source and dynamic destination anybody can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built in Data Export wizard is actually surprisingly good for this kind of thing. In SQL Server Management Studio right click the source database -> Tasks -> export data.

You may have to spend a little time playing around with it but it will allow you to choose the destination database instance & table, you can also manipulate the column mappings.

You can also save the SSIS package it creates at the end as well - its quite a nice way to start with SSIS.

Comment: I know this method. But my package while running mode source and destination table changed and field name and field are different. This scenario how to import. For Example  1. Table1- (col1,col2,col3) 2. Table2- (Col1 ,col2 ,col3 ,col4 ,col5 ) etc., my package is running 24x7. In my package call 1st table then 2nd table and etc.,

Comment: If tables are changing you will need to use data flow source & destination from variables & have some logic in the control flow to build your queries/table names into the variables. You will need a script task to programatically change the mappings at run time based on the new column names. All quite complex unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to migrate data from one table to another table with different schema within same database then you have to mention such as `database1.schema1.table1` as source table and  `database1.schema2.table1` as destination table in execute sql task or data flow task.

similarly, you can adjust any sql statement having this format `[DatabaseName].[Schema].[table]` to any database or schema as per your requirement.

you can migrate data from one server to another server using SSIS Package without using the LINKED server.

You need  simple SSIS Package :

1. Create New SSIS Package and Add Two `OleDB Connection Manager` and configure first one with source database server and second one with destination database server.
2. Add `Data Flow Task` to the package. And then Add `OLE DB Source` and `OLE DB Desination` and configure connection accordingly.

if you need to know more about [how to create a basic ssis package, refer microsoft tutorial](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170419.aspx)

Comment: I know this method. But my package while running mode source and destination table changed and field name and field are different. This scenario how to import. For Example 1. Table1- (col1,col2,col3) 2. Table2- (Col1 ,col2 ,col3 ,col4 ,col5 ) etc., my package is running 24x7. In my package call 1st table then 2nd table and etc.,

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot do this until you know the source and destination table structure upfront. you can't do this at run time without the knowledge of source or destination table structure. if your intention is to backup and restore the database from one server to another server then this is very much possible to automate. you can also generate SSIS package programatically or using ssis variable and for loop container you can migrate data from source to destination.